# Bootstrap inline-form one element pushing label to left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is how it is rendering (in chrome) https://i.stack.imgur.com/TykOo.png

I am looking to do two things:

Make my company dropdown label move to the top like the others, and subsequently push the search box AND company dropdown inline with the rest of fields.

This is not a space issue (or at least I don't think it is). I get the same behaviour if I remove all form elements apart from the company dropdown and contact name.

The generated code:

```
<form action="/TicketViewer" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inquiryID">Inquiry ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inquiryID" name="inquiryID" placeholder="e.g. 7-2931">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contactName">Contact Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactName" name="contactName" placeholder="e.g. gavin (case insensitive) ">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="searchKeyword">Search Keyword</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchKeyword" name="searchKeyword" placeholder="e.g. added mailbox (case insensitive)">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectedCompany">Company</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="SelectedCompany" name="SelectedCompany"><option value=""></option>
<option>SNIPPED</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Engineer</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="engineer" name="engineer">
            <option value="" default selected>All Engineers</option>
            <option>REDACTED LIST/option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's not pure bootstrap, is it? Do you have any CSS for this code?

Comment: Can we see some CSS? With only your HTML it looks fine. See [link](http://www.bootply.com/TTD8PZjsXG)

Comment: Which elements do you want me to post?

Just tried adding a <br /> after the label and it aligned properly - does that help in diagnosing?

Comment: There is probably some CSS interfering with the Bootstrap CSS. Inspect the `.form-group`, `label` and `select` elements in the browser and see if you find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be best to use the bootstrap grid layout to display the form:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
Where you can achieve this layout with a nested grid. Here is an example

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">textbox</div>
   </div>
</div>
```